# Display document only to user who uploaded it in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-security

I have a specific requirement where-in I want only the uploader of the document and a specific team to be able to view it in list / library. 1) is it possible? 2) If yes, how...?

Comment: Do you need it to set as permissions so that there is no way for a curious person to open document through a direct link or you just want to filter a view so that there is no clutter?

Comment: My requirement goes as; Create a list/library where the user who uploads the document will be the one who can view his own uploaded documents. That means as soon as the document is uploaded a permission is set to be accessible only by owner or by a specified SharePoint group. What I did was that I created view where documents will be shown only if they are modified by [Me]. But I want that a specific SharePoint group should be able to see all documents. Any leads..?

Comment: This solution was looking great until the moment that an user with no permissions to view other items clicks on the 'Open with explorer' button. By doing this he'll be able to see every document on that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So I was able to resolve my issue with the steps mentioned below. Soon will be documenting it in form of a blog and share it:

1. Created the document library and modified the default view to only show documents that were created by/modified by [Me].
2. Added a new web page to the library and gave exclusive rights to access that to a certain set of users.
3. Restricted all users from creating a view with the help of creating special permission level where user only had access to upload or delete a document but not creating/updating/deleting lists/views. Also disabled private view creation.

Hope this may be helpful to others too who are looking for restricted views / disabling view creation.

Comment: I think I read that views should not be used for security, because users may still be able to access other users' documents via a direct link.

Comment: I agree with LCountee, users can also click the "Open in Explorer" button which then shows them all documents they have access to.

Comment: What about search?  Wouldn't you be able to see this in search?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set item level permission through event handler:

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-ndash3b-Setting-Item-level-permission.aspx

http://msdnvietnam.net/blogs/quang/archive/2009/07/02/sharepoint-eventhandler-set-item-level-permission.aspx

Comment: Is it possible without custom development...?

Answer (score 1):

@Ashish, in SharePoint 2007 GUI you cannot make a query that will show documents that belongs to a specific group, however CAML specification supports it ([Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544234.aspx) tag), it wasn't documented until SP2010, but it works on SP2007 (i'm using it)

However this involves custom coding and this doesn't assign permissions automatically, it just enables you to filter documents by groups.

For a solution without custom coding you could consider making a seperate folder/list for every person/group and set permissions to folder/list accordingly. This will also help performance - it's better to have permissions set on high-level container than having fine grained permissions (i'm just assuming that, because i read everywhere that mass fine-grained permissions are bad for performance)

Answer (score 0):

You may use current user filter web part to filter the document by whom logged in into the sharepoint site by passing the value Dispaly Name